# How can I get the Utfgrid for the polygon from geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, utfgrids

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBOCu.png)I am using geoserver 2.9.0 to get Utfgrid for polygon, but the response i am getting is Utfgrid as line (border of polygon), instead of that I want a grid as polygon! so is there any way to request geoserver to to get Utfgrid for polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTFGrid is driven by the styles, are you by any chance using a line symbolizer? Make sure you're using a polygon one.

Comment: I am using a polygonsymbolizer, here is my style code for the same

Comment: I have attached a link with my question for my style

Comment: I got the solution. i just need to add style=polygon parameter with my request. thanks for help @Andrea Aime